# Moving master branch to original state before any commits

Tags: git, git-revert

I apologise if this question has already been asked and answered, but I could'nt find it.

Basically, instead of creating a branch, I have implemented a alpha version of an application in the master branch and committed a few times over the top of a forked version of the old application.

Is it possible to revert the master branch back to its original state?

Ben

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529078/git-for-a-beginner-git-reset-hard-head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `git log` to display the commits to the `master` branch.  From this information determine how many commits you would like to remove.

```
$ git log
commit ca82a6dff817ec66f44342007202690a93763949
Author: Scott Chacon <schacon@gee-mail.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 17 21:52:11 2008 -0700

    changed the version number
```

Then use git rebase to remove the specified number of commits.

```
git reset --hard HEAD~3 <--- Number of commits
```

Note that using `--hard` will cause all current changes to be lost.  This answer also assumes that the commits you desire to remove are in a sequential order.

If your working in a collaborative environment use `git revert` instead of `reset`.  This will issue a new commit that overwrites the old commits.

```
git revert HEAD~3..HEAD  <--- 3 being number of commits to overwrite
```

See [this article](http://ariejan.net/2011/09/08/git-remove-reset-and-rollback-commits/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Is this method ok to implement even if other members are working on this repo?

Comment: @PassengerInspired In that case you would use `revert`

Comment: Thanks man, really appreciate your help. One more question, if I have a specific commit I want to revert to what would the command be?

Comment: Use `git revert <commit# here>` where commit# is the sha hash displayed by the log command

Comment: Once I revert, do I have to push back to the remote? I apologise for the multiple questions

Comment: You would need to push the changes to the remote since they would only be on the local repo

Answer (score 0):

try

```
git checkout master 

git reset --hard origin/master
```