# Undo a git merge after origin pull

Tags: github

After not having worked on an app for a long time I started again, and couldn't sort out an error.

So I checkout out a previous local branch, fixed it and then i did this:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git merge new_master
git push origin master
```

(not realizing that I was going to merge it with the previous errors)

Then I tried a few things that I found on stack overflow and now I am completely lost.

How can I backtrack from this?

I have pulled the master from github.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark your current `master` branch (which isn't as you would like)

```
git branch tmp
```

You can reset your master to an older commit (look at the history of master on GitHub, and pick a SHA1 before your push)

```
git reset --hard old_SHA1
```

Then you can look at the history of the local tmp branch, and [cherry-pick the commit(s) you want to apply to `master`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309).

Once this is done, you can force push to origin:

```
git push --force origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to revert it:

Find out the hash of the git merge

> git checkout master 
>   git pull origin master 
>   **git merge new_master** 
>   git push origin master

with `git log`, then ([Undoing Merges](http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html)):

```
$ git revert -m 1 hash_founded
```

But, assuming you want to come back before the **git pull**, you should go for

```
$ git revert -m 2 hash_founded
```

The -m option "specifies the parent number (starting from 1) of the mainline and allows revert to reverse the change relative to the specified parent." ([git revert](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert))

You can always reset as well: [Revert to a previous Git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529078/how-do-i-used-git-reset-hard-head-to-revert-to-a-previous-commit)