# How to find the last commit on a base branch before a merge (with a different branch) occurred?

Tags: git

I would like to revert a pushed merge into a base branch to the state it was right before the merge. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529078/how-do-i-use-git-reset-hard-head-to-revert-to-a-previous-commit

Comment: @Ranjith's: No, it's not. I know how to revert to a previous commit. What I'm looking for is how to find what the last commit on a base branch was before another branch was merged into it, so that I can revert to it.

Comment: ohkk, you try using `git log` to see what commits are made to base branch..

Comment: @Ranjith's: I am well aware of `git log`. However, when you have 100 commits on your feature branch and merge it into the master, then you have these 100 new commits (100 being a figurative number) and it's hard to immediately spot this from the commit log. Hence I'm looking for the exact command which displays this.

Comment: Is your question about reverting the merge changes (as the question says) or about finding the commit to revert to (as your last comment says)?

Comment: Well, ultimately, the goal is to: find the revision before the merge and then revert to it.

Comment: `git log --all --graph` and `gitk` come to mind...

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you know the merge commit to be reverted and only need to find the base of the merge, as I understand from your comments:

First there is a visual way which shows the parent commits. This might help to understand and make sure you get the right commit:

`git show [commit]` (and `git log` too) will print information about your merge commit in this form:

```
commit [commit]
Merge: [parent1] [parent2]
Author: [author]
Date: Tue Jul 19 12:00:00 2016
```

Where parent2 is the merged commit while parent1 is the commit is has been merged to.
Thus this example (`git rev-parse` in this case shows the hash of the given branch):

```
$ git branch
master
$ git rev-parse master
hasha
$ git rev-parse develop
hashb
$ git merge develop
```

Will result in a commit like this one:

```
commit newhash
Merge: hasha hashb
Author: [author]
Date: Tue Jul 19 12:00:00 2016
```

You can also get the respective commits using the ^ shortcut. `master^1` (which is the same as `master^`) will get you the first parent (hasha in the example above), while `master^2` will give you the second parent (hashb). So you can also use these for your revert (in your case you would want to revert to master^1 if your branch were master). You might want to try them out calling `git show master^` to watch which commit is found this way.

Answer (score 1):

Besides [lucash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38463399/1256452) (which is correct and I've upvoted), if you truly want to identify the *merge base* commit(s), you can use [`git merge-base`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-base.html) on the parent commits.

For instance, suppose that the merge in question is commit `a123456` (after being shortened to 7 characters).  As lucash said the two parents are `a123456^1` and `a123456^2` (assuming there are only two parents—for an octopus merge, where there are three or more parents, just keep adding more parent specifiers, e.g., `a123456^3` through `a123456^99` or whatever).  Note that, as [the `git merge-base` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-base.html) says, you need the `--all` flag to show *all* merge bases, in the case where there is more than one merge base.

(If there *is* more than one merge base, the default *recursive* merge strategy will merge them to produce a single "virtual merge base", which is not actually contained in the repository.  You will need the parameters of the merge in order to repeat this process, if you wish to view the virtual merge base result by creating it as an actual physical merge.  While general idea should be pretty obvious, the details are beyond the scope of this answer.)

Note that there is a specific [`gitrevisions` syntax](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) for listing "all parents of a merge": `a123456^@` is equivalent to listing `a123456^1 a123456^2 ... a123456^99` in the hypothetical case of our 99-parent merge commit `a123456`.  Hence, if the name `master` currently points to the merge commit you just made, you can simply run:

```
git merge-base --all master^@
```

to see the hashes of the merge base(s) of the current merge commit.

---

All that said, if you truly want to revert a merge, you generally just want to use `git revert -m <number> <mergecommit>`; and if you want to review the two sides that went in, you generally want something like:

```
git rev-list --left-right --cherry-mark --boundary master^1...master^2
```

(note the three dots), or the same with `rev-list` replaced with `log` or `log --oneline` or similar (incidentally, note that `git log` and `git rev-list` are really almost the same command, just with different output formats).  The `--boundary` option tells Git to include the merge bases themselves (but not their parents), marking them with a leading `-` (which goes well with the `--left-right` and `--cherry-mark` options).  If you want to exclude the merge bases, omit the `--boundary` flag.  See [the (very long) `git rev-list` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) for more details.