# git reset --hard doesn't work unless I specify HEAD~

Tags: git, visual-studio, reset

The problem is if I do the reset from Visual Studio UI it probably sends `git reset --hard` command and doesn't work.

Is there some setting to automatically do `git reset --hard HEAD~` when I do `git reset --hard`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use 'git reset --hard HEAD' to revert to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529078/how-do-i-use-git-reset-hard-head-to-revert-to-a-previous-commit)