# How to make my master same as the one on my Github?

Tags: git, github

My friend made a branch `user` and while I was on my `master` I did `git pull origin user` and now that branch has been merged to my master.

I realised it only after many other changes and commits, but we decided not to implement that branch any more. How do I remove those files from my `master` and make my local master the same as the Github one?

I tried `git reflog` but I'm not sure what information I get there, many commits are being repeated. My `git status` shows my branch is 6 commits ahead.

Comment: Assuming you didn't rewrite history, you can do a simple `git reset HEAD^`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Comment: I edited the question a bit, I stashed some changes but never committed them. Still `git reset HEAD^`

Comment: Are you still in the process of merging? If that's the case, just abort. If not, what's the problem? Just delete the stash.

Comment: Is it done by `git stash clear`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did `git reset --hard origin/master` and it resolved all of my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the not commited changes with a `git reset --hard HEAD`
More infos are here
[How do I use 'git reset --hard HEAD' to revert to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529078/how-do-i-use-git-reset-hard-head-to-revert-to-a-previous-commit)

Answer (score 0):

A) Your uncommitted changes are still there, like you said, you can stash them and add them later.

B) Verify you're on the right branch and do `git reset --hard`, that will revert all changes back and you'll be on the HEAD of the branch