# If I git reset --hard on my local machine, will the repo on github also be resetted?

Tags: git, git-reset

There are 2 commits:

- commit 1: local (did not push to github),  branch "testing", committed roughly 3 minutes ago, features files last edited 5 days ago
- commit 2: online in my github repo (pushed to testing roughly 2.5 hours ago), branch "testing", committed roughly 3 hours ago, features files last edited 3 hours ago

I just pulled the more recent and up-to-date files from the online repo and basically merged them into my local files. But I'd like to [revert that merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch) and see how the changes in commit 1 could still be used ... (with git diff I guess?).

So if I do a hard reset, would that also have an effect on the files in the online repo?

Comment: Unless you do `git push --force`, remote repo won't be affected by changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mostly want, at the moment, to look at a past commit, you probably should just check out that commit as a "detached HEAD".  In detached HEAD mode, you are on *no* branch at all.  Instead, you have checked out some historical commit, which you can now see and work with in your work-tree.

To exit "detached HEAD" mode, pick any branch name and use `git checkout name`.  That puts your work-tree back to the way it should be to work with the latest commit on the named branch, while also putting you on the named branch.

You can also—**at any time**, regardless of branches—use `git diff` on *any two commits* to compare them.  Use `git log` to show your current commit, including its full hash ID, and previous commits, including their full hash IDs.  Then, using your mouse to cut and paste the hashes, because commit hash IDs are way too hard to use otherwise, run:

```
git diff <hash1> <hash2>
```

Git will compare the snapshots in the commits specified by the two hashes, and show you what's *different* in those two commit snapshots.

Meanwhile, to answer the question you did ask:

> So if I do a hard reset, would that also have an effect on the files in the online repo?

No.  Not immediately for sure, because your repository is *your* repository, and their repository—the online one—is *their* repository.  *Nothing* you do in your repository affects them *at all* until you have your Git call up their Git and ask it or tell it: *make some change(s)*.

When you do a `git reset --hard` in your repository, you:

1. Reset your work-tree.

   Your work-tree is where your Git puts the files you can see and work with.  Git does not use them directly.  This is actually the *last* step of `git reset --hard`.  If you use `git reset --mixed` or `git reset --soft`, Git skips this step.
2. Reset your *index*.

   Your Git keeps a copy of all of your current files in its index.  Git also calls the index the *staging area*—these are two terms for the same thing.  Doing a `git reset --hard` tells your Git: *Make all the index copies of files match the commit copies.*  This is actually the *second* step of `git reset --hard`.  If you use `git reset --soft`, Git skips this step.
3. Change the commit identified by your current branch name.

   This is the first step of any of these kinds of `git reset`.  Your current branch name, such as `master` or `testing`, currently identifies *one specific commit*.  All other commits that are on the branch are found by starting<sup>1</sup> at this one commit and working backwards.

   When you use `git reset --soft`, `git reset --mixed`, or `git reset --hard`, you get to pick out *any* commit you like, *anywhere* in your repository.  Use `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` to get a really big view of every commit in your repository, including their shortened hash IDs.  You can now pick any commit you like, use your mouse to cut-and-paste its ID, and use `git reset` to make your current branch name *that one particular commit*.  The one commit your branch named before?  Well, that one no longer matters much: the branch name now names the commit you picked out.  Git will start there and work backwards through time to find all the earlier commits.  Any commits *after* that point are no longer on your branch.

   You *can* pick the commit that the branch already names!  If you are on `master`, and `master` names commit `deadcab`, and you `git reset --hard deadcab`, the first step of the `git reset` is to change `master` from naming commit `deadcab` to instead name commit `deadcab`.  This of course changes absolutely nothing: the name still identifies commit `deadcab`.  So the only *observable* effect is the reset to the index, and the reset to the work-tree.

   If you pick some *other* commit, though, this changes the commit identified by the branch name.

Later, when you run `git push`, you have your Git call up some other Git.  Your Git talks with that other Git.  Your Git gives them any commits that you have that they don't have (but that they need—your Git generally won't give them commits they don't need), then your Git will ask their Git: *Hey, other Git!  Please change some of your branch names, so that your branch names specify these particular commit hash IDs.*  The branch names your Git asks them to change, and the hash IDs your Git asks them to use, generally come from *your* branch names, using the hash IDs *your* branch names specify.

It's at `git push` time that your Git sends things to the other Git.  At `git fetch` time—note that `git fetch` is the first part of `git pull`—your Git calls up their Git, but in this direction, your Git gets new commits from them, and then your Git updates your `origin/*` *remote-tracking names*,<sup>2</sup> rather than doing anything with any of *your* branches.

---

<sup>1</sup>I mistyped this as "staring at", at first.  That's kind of appropriate.  Git has to stare at the commit for a while, to find the previous commit.  Then it stares at the previous commit, to find the next one back. :-)  Each commit lists the hash ID of the commit that comes before it.  These are the *parent commit IDs* that you'll see talked about elsewhere.

<sup>2</sup>This assumes you have exactly one remote, named `origin`, which is typically true, but not actually required.

Comment: Well, it depends on your push / fetch. If the other Git likes your request, their branch now equals your branch! That's probably beer-worthy. If they don't like your request for whatever reason, they reject it, which might call for drowning your own sorrows, but probably alone. :-) For `git fetch`, your Git renames their branch names to your remote-tracking names, so the next part is up to you: if you use `git merge`—which is `git pull`'s *second* command by default—then you're incorporating their commits into yours, but that gets a lot more complicated.

Comment: Fwiw, just so you know: someone, not me, removed my comment with the beer question.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to your question `NO` unless you perform `git push <<*remote-branch-name*>>`
Entire explanation of `git reset --hard HEAD` is explained in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529078/how-do-i-use-git-reset-hard-head-to-revert-to-a-previous-commit)..! This should help with other related question you might have.