# How is work the git reset command for overwrite local changes with remote

Tags: git, command, git-branch, git-reset

I am new in git and read some information about this command `git reset --hard @{u}` for resetting your local changes and overwriting them with the branch's remote changes. But I don't have a clear idea yet about how is work this instruction, hope you can help with some practical examples.
Thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use 'git reset --hard HEAD' to revert to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529078/how-do-i-use-git-reset-hard-head-to-revert-to-a-previous-commit)

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified