# Revert merged PR from git master branch

Tags: git, git-merge, git-revert

I have 2 git branches master and develop. master is production ready and develop is live development branches. I opened a PR to merge develop changes into master which had changes and commits which does not suppose to go in production. Since this PR is merged into master with multiple commits from multiple developer how i can revert it back to its original state?

Thanks

Comment: Did you actually do a search? There are already _plenty_ of questions about this

Comment: Yes i did but I am bit conscious as it is master branch and need specific answer to my query

Comment: Just try the solutions out first. If you made a mistake, just don't push your changes and reset your changes or clone a fresh copy. You can also create the same situation on a local test repo. At least post your reserached answers / blog posts etc. in the question so someone can tell if that leads in the right direction.

Comment: Unless you specify what is different in your case compared to the cases which answer you don't want to try out, you will end up getting the same answer anyway...

Answer (score -1):

You can either do the reset branch to specified commit

```
git reset --hard <COMMIT>
```

And then push your changes - it will require force push permissions tough.
Here's a nice explanation on how it works - [How do I use 'git reset --hard HEAD' to revert to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529078/how-do-i-use-git-reset-hard-head-to-revert-to-a-previous-commit)

Your other option is to just create a new master branch, basing on last good commit of your current master branch.

And of course you can just revert all the commits, but this would mess up your git history